# System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, directx, filenotfoundexception

This one is a long story: i have recently built a win32 application in Visual Studio that uses DirectX and I sent it to some friends to verify that it works on other machines. They all had .NET installed, but the app didn't worked for all of my friends.

In two cases there we're some "could not load file or assembly Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput version 1.0.29..." errors when they tried to run the program.

I figured that they must have other versions of the .dll and, after some checking, i found out that my references we're to fixed versions. I changed the "fixed version" property to false to all of the directX dlls, but they still got errors when they tried to run the application.

Finally i tried to copy all the dlls in the same folder with the app and the directx errors were gone, but they instead got a "System.IO.FileNotFoundException the specified module could not be found" error at the line where the program tried to make a Direct3D.Texture from an image (the link to the image was correct).

If you can help me with hints for fixing any of the problems above, i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will find that you will get better answers if you post the code in question... It is difficult to determine what is wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Which Managed DirectX implementation are you using? SlimDX? XNA? Something else?

Comment: @Oded: Thank you! I can already say it's good to be here. Well, I could post the code, but i don't see how that could be of any use, since the problem is with the references (which are not exactly in the code as far as I can tell).

@Aren B: uhm...ok, i admit, i don't understand that question. It's basically just C# with the plain .dlls from .NET ( managed directx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Managed DirectX, and some of your friends probably don't have it installed.  As far as I can tell, the redistributable package for MDX is not available anymore. (Not from Microsoft anyway, you might be able to find it somewhere)

Note that Managed DirectX is basically obsolete and in many cases [XNA](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/) is a better choice.

Comment: For the record, XNA replaced Managed DirectX, but it's **NOTHING** like it. XNA is a game framework, not a managed portal to directx.

Comment: @Aren B: I see your point. In this case, what would you propose for me to work with? I just started real programming and i'm still not sure which way to go first: there is DirectX, but there's also OpenGL, XNA as a framework, etc. (for the language i will definetly stick to C# for now) What would you say the best combination is?

Comment: @cantrem SlimDX, I haven't played with it, but it's the spiritual successor to Managed DirectX. Gives you more direct access to DX vs. too many layers of abstraction.

Comment: @Aren Here comes the fun part: I have a Windows Application using SlimDX (for Joystick Input), I just deployed it to another machine and got an FileNotFoundException ... googleing SlimDX + FileNotFoundException brought me here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ManagedDirectX than there's the Quick and Dirty way of fixing this problem. and thats just copying the ManagedDirectX dll's into the same directory. MS Says it won't work and it's definitely not very suitable for production envs. But it'll work in most cases.

DLL's are at least:

```
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.dll
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll
Microsoft.DirectX.dll
```

Comment: Yea. Quick, but very dirty. And, in this case, it didn't worked (in my first post i wrote that another interesting error poped up when i made copies of the dlls in the app folder).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be resolved by now.

I too was experiencing the same issue for 2 days now and I finally resolved it. I tried out so many solutions that were suggested on the web but nothing worked for me. My project references another project which in turn was referencing Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll. When I ran the project I got the exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

It turns out that this dll was searching for 'one of its dependencies' and couldn't find them since I didn't have DirectX installed on my machine. So the solution for me was to install DirectX.

Refer the following link for DirectX web installer:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35

I hope this helps others who face the same problem! :)